# Specify norestart on msi installation executed through visual c++ app

Tags: c++, windows-installer

I am using the MsiConfigureProduct function to install/uninstall an app that restarts after installation.  I want the the install/uninstall to be silent and unattended but I cannot figure out how to make it norestart.

To make the install/uninstall silent i used

```
MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE, 0);
```

To achieve this from the command line i use

```
msiexec /i InstallPCKG.msi /quiet /norestart
```

I would like to use the msi.dll api so i can determine if the install/uninstall was successful

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MsiConfigureProductEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370071%28VS.85%29.aspx) and set the command line to

```
REBOOT="ReallySuppress"
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371101(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need/want to use msi.dll ? Isn't the return code from msiexec enough (and easier) to figure out the result ? It should be zero on success and non zero on failure.